# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\\Db' not found. for Phalcon 4

Tags: php-7, phalcon

I am currently upgrading version PHP 5 to PHP 7. And Phalcon 1 to Phalcon 4.
my all existing API gives error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Db' not found.

I have found that use Phalcon\Db\Enum instead of Phalcon\Db.
but I want to use Phalcon\Db. Is there any way to use?

Please help me as because of this I have made many changes in my project.

Comment: which version of php are you using php 7.3 or 7.2 or 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per phalcon's docs for phalcon4.0 you will have to use ENUM
https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/api/phalcon_db

You can use phalcon3.4 in case if you want to use Phalcon/Db
https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/api/phalcon_db